# How to animate Bootstrap dropdown icon when it's hovered

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Bootstrap 3 navbar like this:

```css
.has-navbar {
  margin-top: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #fff !important;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-item {
  height: 30px;
  width: max-content;
}

.nav-item a {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.first-item {
  margin-right: -50px !important;
}

.custom-toggler .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(255, 204, 50, 0.5)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.custom-toggler.navbar-toggler {
  border-color: #FFCC32;
}

.user-actions-off {
  display: none;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  border: 0 !important;
}

.navbar-toggler:focus,
.navbar-toggler:active,
.navbar-toggler-icon:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  border: 0 !important;
}

.toggler-icon {
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #FFCC32;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.middle-bar {
  margin: 5px auto;
}

.navbar-toggler .top-bar {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 10% 10%;
}

.navbar-toggler .middle-bar {
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}

.navbar-toggler .bottom-bar {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 10% 90%;
}

.navbar-toggler.collapsed .top-bar {
  transform: rotate(0);
}

.navbar-toggler.collapsed .middle-bar {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}

.navbar-toggler.collapsed .bottom-bar {
  transform: rotate(0);
}

.navbar-toggler.collapsed .toggler-icon {
  background-color: #FFCC32;
}

.navbar .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #FFCC32;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  transition: all 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform-origin: top center;
  transform: scale(1, 0);
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="has-navbar">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <button class="navbar-toggler custom-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="toggler-icon top-bar"></span>
                <span class="toggler-icon middle-bar"></span>
                <span class="toggler-icon bottom-bar"></span>
            </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active bg-warning first-item m-1">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item bg-warning m-1 dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i> Courses</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 2</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 3</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item bg-warning m-1">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>E-learning products</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item bg-warning m-1">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-newspaper"></i> Articles</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item bg-warning m-1">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Events</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Now I need to animate the dropdown icon next to the link when the menu item is hovered:

[image]

So it would looked to the UP when it's hovered (something like this):

[image]

But I don't know really how to do that...

So how can I animate this dropdown icon when it's hover over and make it looking up ?

Comment: I made you a snippet. It is not clear what you need. Also Bootstrap is now in version 5

Comment: Can you provide a more concise snippet? I don't see any "arrow" either so I don't really know what's what